# Почему - волчок?

Tags: этимология

Может быть, глупый вопрос, но почему юла иначе называется волчок? Какое она может иметь отношение к волку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Фасмера так:
Волчоґк. Ближайшая этимология: Ср. лтш. vilks 1. "волчок", 2. "бондарный инструмент, с помощью которого натягивают обручи на деревянную посуду". По М. -- Э. (4, 589), связано с лтш. vilks, русск. Волк, потому что, например, и в немецком языке разные инструменты носят название "волк". Горяев (ЭС 54) сравнивает русск. слово со словом Волочиґться (по земле); см. Волочиґть. Страницы: 1,346-347

И ещё одно толкование:

ВОЛЧОК. Искон. Уменьшит.-ласкат. от волк в значении "волчок" (ср. чешск. vlk "волчок"). Игрушка получила свое название по "воющему" звуку.
Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь, 2004

Answer (score 0):

Всегда считал, что волчок связано со способностью щенков (волка - в том чивле) крутиться на месте, ловя свой хвост. Об это же свидетельствует и существование нареяис "волчком". Крайне сомнительно, что оно могло образоваться от самого "волчка" как вторичного значения. Сравните: калачиком от формы (коло - круг), а не хлеба.